# Excel- find match between to columns but copy a different cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to be able to find matches between two columns in Excel. Lets say Column A and Column C. However Column A's values are linked to Column B. When a match is found in A, can it copy the corresponding row value from B into another sheet?

Comment: Another worksheet in the same file?  Can you reference the value in B from the other sheet?  It might help to provide an example.

Comment: If you're using VBA, you can do about anything.  An example would be helpful.

Comment: give a sample data with a clear example + expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the following data in 'Sheet 1':

Col A  ; Col B  ; Col C

1     ;     131    ;    3

2     ;     125     ;   5

3    ;      168    ;   2

4     ;     154    ;    8

5    ;     1365     ;   0

If I understand the requirement of your question correctly, 
use the following formula in the sheet you want to have your corresponding value appear:

> =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5,0)),"VALUE DOES NOT MATCH",Sheet1!B1)

Comment: you're most welcome!